# Circuissonne Diagrams

Tags: logical-deduction, board-games, physics

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #7: Board games](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/monthly-topic-challenge-7-board-games?cb=1).</sub>

---

<sub>And also, this puzzle is also a parody of XKCD's 730.</sub>

We're starting a project on Explain XKCD (link currently not available) to create a new esoteric board game that is a mix of Carcassonne and XKCD 730.
We'll use circuit symbols instead of roads and cities.

We haven't decided on the use of the features but here's a simple puzzle based on my ideas.

Alice is playing a game of Circuissonne (citation needed) and she had already claimed this light bulb. During this turn of hers, there are two identical tiles in her hand (both in the shape of the green tile on the right). Power source is 1V 0Ω, all resistors are 1Ω, diode is 0Ω, wire resistance is ignored. The light bulb is 1V 1W. She is supposed to place the two tiles in the proper place on the board.

Basic Carcassonne rules apply (citation needed).

What is the optimal play, which makes the light bulb the brightest?

---

Please upload an ASCII art version if possible, as I don't have access to Imgur images.

[image]

Comment: I can't solve it!

Comment: How exactly is the brightness of a bulb determined? Are you merely asking for maximum _current_ through the bulb?